# Accept mails only for a certain address with Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, mail-transport-agent

How do you configure a mail server to only accept mails on a certain address?
For example, my mail server should only accept mail on `example@myths.ops` and not `example@harpy.myths.ops`. I've looked everywhere, including the configuration files for postfix and ssmtp but couldn't seem to find an option to do this.

Comment: Accepting only valid email addresses and rejecting others should be what Postfix does by default in pretty much any reasonable configuration. Can you edit to include more details about your setup? For example are `myths.ops` and `harpy.myths.ops` virtual alias domains or something else?